# TypeError: unsupported operand types for 'list' & 'int'

Tags: python

This is supposed to verify a line has an IP in it and then print the line but I am receiving

```
TypeError: unsupported operand types for 'list' & 'int'
```

I cannot think of a solution for my current code, can anyone lend a hand?

```
import sys

import re
match = 0

def CheckIP(ip, filter):

    match = re.compile(b"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$", ip)
    if match == None:
        print ("No IP's in this file!")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        pass

with open('text.log') as f:

    x=[]
    count = 0
    for l in f:
        x = l.strip().split("\t")[5:8] # Grab the elements you want...
        x.pop(1) #... but remove the element you don't
        CheckIP(x, match)
        print(" ".join(x)) # Now print them
        print('\n')
        count += 1
        if count == 20:
                print("\n\n\n\n\n-----NEW GROUPING OF 20 RESULTS-----\n\n\n\n\n\n")
                count = 0

print(count)
```

---

Modified:

```
import sys
import re

with open('text.log') as f:

    x=[]
    count = 0
    for l in f:
        x = l.strip().split("\t")[5:8] # Grab the elements you want...
        x.pop(1) #... but remove the element you don't
        match = re.compile("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$", x)
        if any(lambda s: match.search(s) for s in x):
            pass
        else:
            print ("No IP's in this file!")
            sys.exit(0)
        print(" ".join(x)) # Now print them
        print('\n')
        count += 1
        if count == 20:
                print("\n\n\n\n\n-----NEW GROUPING OF 20 RESULTS-----\n\n\n\n\n\n")
                count = 0

print(count)
```

Error:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 76, in exec_file
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)

  File "C:\Users\marco\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PythonApplication4\
PythonApplication4\a2.py", line 10, in <module>match = re.compile("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$", x)

  File "D:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 219, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)

  File "D:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 275, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'int'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Show us the complete error message you're getting.

Comment: @jwodder Apologies, added the error.

Comment: Why are you passing `match` to `CheckIP()`? That becomes your `filter` parameter, which is never used.

Comment: It is supposed to verify an IP has 4 numbers and is in the 0-255 range.

Comment: You are using the wrong method. The second argument of `compile` is a list of flags, not the string to match against. Maybe you were looking for `match` or `search` instead?

Comment: @tobias_k I tried match but I then get the error "expected string or buffer"

Answer (score 8):

You're using [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) incorrectly.  The second argument is supposed to be an integer formed by bitwise-ORing `re` flags together, not a list of strings to match against.

The simplest way to do what you appear to be trying to do is:

```
pattern = re.compile(  ### regex ### )
if any(pattern.search(s) for s in ip):
    pass
else:
    print ("No IP's in this file!")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Okay, I attempted your method and will leave out the function for now but I seem to be receiving the same error! Am I still doing the same thing wrong? I have added the new error and modified code @jwodder?

Comment: @user3788715: Don't pass `x` to `re.compile`.  Pass just the regex and nothing else: `match = re.compile("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$")`

Comment: Alright, I am using visual studios and I am now receiving GeneratorExit occurred. I cant find any documentation on how to fix this do you have an experience with it?
It is happening on this line "if any(lambda s: match.search(s) for s in x):" @jwodder

Comment: @user3788715: I'm an idiot and wrote the `any` expression wrong.  The `lambda s:` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thats okay haha @jwodder so it should just be "if any(match.search(s) for s in x):"

Comment: Thank you for all your help @jwodder but one last question how would I then append the list with the results from the search? The program either prints everything or exits with no ips found with any of the solutions I try.

Comment: @user3788715: I think that's veering too far off into another question that should be asked separately.